# Are there Z Transparency in Blender 2.80 or above?

Tags: transparency

I would like to ask where is Z Transparency and how does it looks like in Blender 2.8 and above?[image]

This image shown above is around the 2.78 version of Blender. Which is before 2.8 came.

Answer (score 1):

Directly, no. Practically, yes. Z transparency was a component of materials for the blender internal render engine, which was discontinued with 2.80.

I’m guessing the problem you are encountering is that your materials have been either non-transparent or dead black.

How to fix: In EEVEE, you must manually set the blend method of the material to something besides “opaque.” Said settings panel is by default at the bottom of the Properties editor -> Materials tab. Your options are:

1. Opaque. Ignores transparency. If pure transparency comes in, it turns black.
2. Alpha Blend. Tries to do full alpha mixing. Has had trouble working correctly with more than one face in a row.
3. Alpha clip. Either fully opaque or fully transparent.
4. Alpha hashed. Like alpha clip, but with a random threshold. Good for most applications if you don’t mind a little fuzz. More rendering samples will provide better results.